"history" command ordered by most common
Can I get the output of history sorted in order of most-used?
I know how to do it in a programming language, but not from the shell. In my case I'm on macOS with zsh.
I know I could use uniq and sort and something to strip off the initial number field in the history output. But that would only be deduplicated and not take into account 'frequency of duplication'.
Is this even possible in shell or should I turn to a programming language?

You can remove the initial number by calling passing the -n flag to history or fc.
To sort by frequency, use the -c flag to uniq and sort again by that value.
The following snippet shows your 20 most often used used commands. Remove the sed step if you want to keep the repeat count. Remove the tail step if you want the whole list.
fc -n -l 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1n | sed 's/^ *[0-9][0-9]* //' | tail -n20

Of course this assumes you don't enable options like hist_ignore_dups, otherwise the information is lost.

It seems to malfunction under macos or zsh. Some output lines seem to be partial commands: % fc -n -l 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1n | cut -c9- | tail -n20 ->
foo.ts && node foo.js
build run --
go run a
t hello_world.dart 

I think the problem happens at cut -c9-

@hippietrail Ah, yes, BSD uniq and GNU uniq use a different width for the number. I've changed to strip just the number, whatever its width.

Just forking Giles' great answer to show how it can be extended and used in practice. I decided for my use case and for my personal preference, to use it this way:
fc -n -l 1 | grep git | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1nr | head -n20


+ | grep git - lets me see only the subset of commands I'm interested in. Here, git commands.
| sort -k1n | tail -n20 → | sort -k1nr | head -n20 - I prefer to see most-used first so I added r to reverse the sort, which necessitates looking at the head instead of the tail.

I can then turn that into a new command using alias like so:
alias most='f() { fc -n -l 1 | grep "\<$1\>" | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1nr | head -n20 };f'

In this case I've called the new command most.
